# Check xml tags for certain values and transform - Best practice

Tags: java, xml, xslt, batch-processing

I want to do the following :
At this moment we receive some xml-files where some xml-tags are filled wrongly.
To help our partner, we want to catch these false values by using a "Pass-through" folder where all the xml-files are placed before importing in our application.

This folder would be read every X minutes and for every file there will need to be done some checks, like : The length of the value within a tag, the value of the tag, etc.

Because this is only a temporary solution, we don't want to implement it in our application.

I was thinking of 2 possible set-ups :

- Using java and calling an XSLT-file to transform every file and put it in another folder
- Using only java to check the xml-file and do the transformation.
  Both of the cases would be called by a .bat that runs every X minutes.

Now my questions :

- What do you think that would be the best solution? a.k.a. the quickest, the most secure, etc. (maybe something other than suggested?)
- Could you also provide me some examples of the way to do something like this?

I'm not like other persons who ask strictly for the codes. If you can give me something similar, I can make it on my own.
At the time of this writing, I'm already looking for solutions on other websites, but because it is urgent, it's also helpfull to ask the community.

Thank you for your answer,
Kind regards,
Maarten

EDIT : Both answers helped me a lot. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html

or

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.validation/how-to-create-xml-validator-from-xml-s.html

or

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your XSLT, using a .bat script, on every XML file in a given folder (your first option in the OP) I can think of 3 ways:

---

**A.** Basically do a "for" loop to process each individual file via the command line. (Eww.)

---

**B.** Use `collection()` to point to an input folder and use `xsl:result-document` to create the output files in a new folder.

**Here's an example XSLT 2.0** (tested with Saxon 9):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="pInputDir" select="'input'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pOutputDir" select="'output'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vCollection" select="collection(concat($pInputDir,'/?*.xml'))"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$vCollection">
      <xsl:variable name="vOutFile" select="tokenize(document-uri(document(.)),'/')[last()]"/>
      <xsl:result-document href="{concat($pOutputDir,'/',$vOutFile)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>   
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Notes:**

This stylesheet is just doing an identity transform. It's passing the XML through unchanged. You would need to override the identity template by adding new templates to do your checks/changes.

Also notice that there are 2 parameters for the input and output folder names.

You may run into memory issues using `collection()` because it loads all of the XML files in the folder into memory. If this is an issue, see below...

---

**C.** Have your XSLT process a list of all the files in the directory. Use a combination of `document()` and the Saxon extension function `saxon:discard-document()` to load and discard the documents.

Here's an example I used a while back for testing.

**XML file listing (input to the XSLT):**

```
<files>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file1.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file2.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file3.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file4.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file5.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file6.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file7.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file8.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file9.xml</file>
  <file>file:///C:/input_xml/file10.xml</file>
</files>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (tested with Saxon 9):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="pOutputDir" select="'output'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="files">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:variable name="vOutFile" select="tokenize(document-uri(document(.)),'/')[last()]"/>
    <xsl:result-document href="{concat($pOutputDir,$vOutFile)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document(.)/saxon:discard-document(.)" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>          
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Notes:**

Again, this stylesheet is just doing an identity transform. It's passing the XML through unchanged. You would need to override the identity template by adding new templates to do your checks/changes.

Also notice that there is only a parameter for the output folder name.